# Using a key value in an object in the same object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value from an array in a object.

So two cases;

First if the key and value is in the same object.
Second if the key is being used in another object.

```
const direction = {
    'N': ['E', 'W', 0],
    'E': ['S', 'N', 0],
    'S': ['W', 'E', 0 * Math.sign(-1)],
    'W': ['N', 'S', 0 * Math.sign(-1)],
    x: this.N[2] // Trying to get The value from 'N' in the array
  }
```

AND

```
const value = { x: direction.N[2]} //calling the value from the above object
```

Comment: If you mark down can you say why? might be simple for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a method i could return the values. Is there an issue doing it like this?
why use a class?

```
const direction = {
    'N': ['E', 'W', 0],
    'E': ['S', 'N', 0],
    'S': ['W', 'E', 0 * Math.sign(-1)],
    'W': ['N', 'S', 0 * Math.sign(-1)],
    x() {return this.W[2] + this.E[2]},
    y() {return this.N[2] + this.S[2]}
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to create either a class and set your properties inside of the class or the `constructor` or create a function to generate new objects. The syntax you're attempting to use is not possible.

```js
class Direction {
  N = ['E', 'W', 0];
  E = ['S', 'N', 0];
  S = ['W', 'E', 0 * Math.sign(-1)];
  W = ['N', 'S', 0 * Math.sign(-1)];
  x = this.N[2];
}

const direction = new Direction();

console.log(direction);
// Direction {N: Array(3), E: Array(3), S: Array(3), W: Array(3), x: 0}
```

Or:

```js
function createDirection() {
  let direction = {
    'N': ['E', 'W', 0],
    'E': ['S', 'N', 0],
    'S': ['W', 'E', 0 * Math.sign(-1)],
    'W': ['N', 'S', 0 * Math.sign(-1)],
  };

  direction.x = direction.N[2];
  return direction;
}

console.log(createDirection());
// {N: Array(3), E: Array(3), S: Array(3), W: Array(3), x: 0}
```

Using a class has the advantage of allowing additional functions and computed properties (`get property() {}` syntax) on your object, which will make your code more readable and extendable.

Comment: Hi mat thank you. will look over class and constructor again. Thank you

Comment: keep objects simple? can methods be used inside objects? eg. something() => {}

Comment: Yes, you can define methods in classes.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use object initializer like this. It is logically incorrect.

And also if you want to use the items of 'N' array, you can use like following:

```js
const direction = {
    'N': ['E', 'W', 0],
    'E': ['S', 'N', 0],
    'S': ['W', 'E', 0 * Math.sign(-1)],
    'W': ['N', 'S', 0 * Math.sign(-1)]
  }
  
  console.log(direction)
  console.log(direction['N'][2])
```